# TypeError Supplied fullPermissions is not an Array of GuildApplicationCommandPermissionData with Slash Commands Permissions (v13 Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a Discord bot and it has 3 sensitive slash commands meant for only moderators. I am working on trying to make sure only people with the moderator role can use the command, and the `@everyone` role is denied. However, when I start the bot (it deploys all commands if there are updates) it throws this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied
> fullPermissions is not an Array of
> GuildApplicationCommandPermissionData.

Here is my `permissions.json`:

```
[
    {
        "guild": 784526382788771870,
        "id": 872515078224748606,
        "permissions": [
            {
                "id": 784539540101660712,
                "type": 1,
                "permission": true
            },
            {
                "id": 784526382788771870,
                "type": 1,
                "permission": false
            }
        ]  
    }
]
```

Note: this is only one slash command's permissions.

Update: it still doesn't work when I remove the `"id": 784539540101660712,` in each role's permissions for the command.

Comment: Where is the code that uses `fullPermissions` etc?

Comment: How do you add these permissions? `commands.permissions.set` or `commands.permissions.add`?

Comment: Using `.add` threw this error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied command is not a ApplicationCommandResolvable.`

Comment: I went in the source code and found it expects a `ApplicationCommand` or `Snowflake`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I looked at the source code and the permissions attribute had to be in the ApplicationCommand object itself.

Answer (score 0):

`GuildApplicationCommandPermissionData` does not have property "guild". Each `GuildApplicationCommandPermissionData` should only have 1 `id` and an array of `ApplicationCommandPermissionData` for the `permissions` property.